# How can i append database table column name as key to a list to convert it as dict

Tags: python

I have a for loop which constructs a result some thing like this

```
result =[[1,stu1,grade A],[2,stu2,grade B]]
```

I want to convert it like this

```
result = [id:1,name:stu1,grade: grade A],[id:2, name: stu2, grade:grade B]
```

where id,name,grade is the column name of a Table. I have a loop like this

```
result = []
for stu_details in stu.details:
      result.append([stu_details.id,stu_details.name,stu_details.grade])
```

How can i return my result along with the column name? can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by below code

```
result =[[1,'stu1','grade A'],[2,'stu2','grade B']]
title = ('id', 'name', 'grade')
map(lambda x: dict(zip(title, x)), result)
```

Result would be

```
[{'grade': 'grade A', 'id': 1, 'name': 'stu1'},
    {'grade': 'grade B', 'id': 2, 'name': 'stu2'}]
```

Comment: @@MaNKuR: Thanks a lot. This is what i wanted to do. And it worked

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> dict(zip(('id', 'name', 'grade'), [1, 'stu1', 'A']))
{'grade': 'A', 'id': 1, 'name': 'stu1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is a built-in function made for this usage.

```
>>> dict(zip(('id', 'name', 'grade'), [1, 'stu1', 'A']))
{'grade': 'A', 'id': 1, 'name': 'stu1'}
```

If you list is si huge for memory you can use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), it has the same behavior but with [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) style.